# HTML TO PDF IN NEW WINDOW with Angular 1.58

Tags: angularjs, pdf

I would like to do this in my **Angular 1.5.8** Aplication:

Click on a button and open a new tab window with a PDF. This PDF will have the content from a HTML `<div>` like the code below:

```
<div>
    Teste
</div>
<button> btn </button>
```

For example, if you click on [this link](http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) you will open a PDF in your browse, I would like to do it but the content is inside my html div

I would like to just create a PDF from HTML and just open it in new tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and download pdf from div on angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939447/create-and-download-pdf-from-div-on-angular-2)

Comment: I am using Angular 1.5.8 and I would like to create and open in new tab.